# R get() function error

Tags: r

I'm trying to populate a set of
matrices  where the matrix (object) names are held in a list. I can
use the get() to return the object with the given name, but I'm
running into function problems when I use get() to define the matrix
object I'm trying to populate.

```
#Create list of matrix names:
list.names <- c("m.1")

#Create matrix object
m.1 <- matrix(nrow=2,ncol=2)

#Return matrix m.1 from the list.names using get(). Works great!
get(list.names[1])

#Populate m.1 with some values. Doesn't work.
get(list.names[1]) <- c(1,2,3,4)
```

So in the last line of code, I'm getting an error:

could not find function "get<-"

Similarly, I can call m.1 using:

```
eval(as.name(list.name[1]))
```

But R returns a similar 'could not find function' error when I try to populate the matrix.

Could someone explain the error in my approach, here?

**Edit/Update:**

So in my attempt to simplify the question for posting here, I realized that I may have oversimplified what I'm attempting to do.

So, in fact, I'm attempting to populate elements within a set of matricies. The names of the matrices are contained in the list.names object. I'm using nested for() loops to populate each element within the matrices.

So, in fact, my problem would be more accurately stated as:

```
get(list.names[1])[1,1] <- some_value
```

A couple of the replies have suggested that I use assign based upon my original post, but given that I'm attemping to 'assign' an element within the object rather than the whole object , this approach won't work.

Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I think you want `assign` as in `assign(get(list.names[1]), 1:4)`.  I can't explain the specifics, but an explanation could sound something like: the object returned from `get`doesn't have an assignment  (`<-`) method which is what is indicated by the error.  All with the caveat that you almost never need this sort of gymnastics to achieve a similar result.  Expanding on this in another question may yield some better answers, understanding and code.

Comment: @Justin Not quite. It is `get()` that doesn't have an assignment function not the object returned by `get()`. Essentially there is no `'get<-'()` function and hence the error. It is the parser that sees this sort of construct and converts it into a call to `'get<-'(x = list.names[1], value = c(1,2,3,4))` before it even evaluates the arguments and hence the error about there not being a function `"get<-"`.

Answer (score 5):

This is addressed in FAQ 7.21.  The most important part of that FAQ is the end where it says to use a list (a real list, not the vector that you are calling a list above).  A lot of things become much easier if you have a list of matricies instead of a bunch of matricies in your global work space.  Here is an example:

```
mnames <- c('m.1','m.2','m.3')
m.1 <- matrix(1, 2, 2)
m.2 <- matrix(2, 2, 2)
m.3 <- matrix(3, 2, 2)

## put matricies into a list
mymats <- lapply( mnames, get )
names(mymats) <- mnames

## change 1 value in each matrix a different way
mymats[['m.2']][1,1] <- 22
mymats[[1]][2,2] <- 11
tmp <- "m.3"
mymats[[tmp]][1,2] <- 33

## change the same element in each matrix using a loop
for( i in seq_along(mymats) ) {
 mymats[[i]][2,1] <- 44
}

## apply the same function to every matrix and simplify the output
sapply( mymats, rowMeans )
```

This is much simpler than messing around with `get` and `assign`.

Answer (score 3):

Use function `assign` instead of `get`:

```
assign(list.names[1],c(1,2,3,4))
```

`get` returns an object's  value, `assign` assigns. :)

Same thing with `eval`, it just evaluates your call.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Can assign be used to change/populate a single element in the Object? In reality, my code is a series of nested loops where I am using secondary functions to generate element values. I tried: assign(list.names[1][1,1],1) without luck.

Comment: You might want to look at `with` and `within`, ...  `assign` creates an object with a name, whereas `with` and `within` allow access to internal components. Why not put in a more accurate description of you problem?