# Copying dimnames without copying objects?

Tags: r

I could not find a prior question about this, but [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15303972/r-get-function-error) is fairly close.

Often I make new objects and want them to have the same dimnames (`names`, `colnames`, `rownames`) as some other object. Normally, I would use `names`, or `rownames` + `colnames`, but I'm tired of doing this and I want a better solution. I also want a solution that allows for partial matching, so I need a new function. My trouble is that it is apparently not quite easy to get it exactly right.

First, a helper function:

```
get_dims = function(x) {
  if (is.null(dim(x))) {
    return(length(x))
    } else {
    return(dim(x))
  }
}
```

This gets the dimensions of any object. `dim()` returns `NULL` for atomic objects (vectors and lists), whereas it really should just return their length.

Next, we make up some minimal test data:

```
t = matrix(1:9, nrow=3)
t2 = t
rownames(t) = LETTERS[1:3]; colnames(t) = letters[1:3]
```

Inspect:

```
> t
  a b c
A 1 4 7
B 2 5 8
C 3 6 9
> t2
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
```

The test is that `t2` should get the dimnames of `t`. I print them because `==` apparently cannot handle list comparison (returns `logical(0)`).

A simple solution is to take in the object whose names I want to copy, the object where I want to copy them to, and simply change the dimnames in the function and return the object back. This can be done like this:

```
copy_names1 = function(x, y, partialmatching = T) {

  #find object dimensions
  x_dims = get_dims(x)
  y_dims = get_dims(y)

  #set names if matching dims
  if (all(x_dims == y_dims)) {
    #loop over each dimension
    for (dim in 1:length(dimnames(x))) {
      dimnames(y)[[dim]] <- dimnames(x)[[dim]]
    }
  }

  return(y)
}
```

Test:

```
> copy_names1(t, t2)
  a b c
A 1 4 7
B 2 5 8
C 3 6 9
```

So it works fine, but returns the object, which means one has to use the assignment operator, which is not needed with the normal *`names()` functions.

We can also assign from within the function using `assign()`:

```
copy_names2 = function(x, y, partialmatching = T) {

  #find object dimensions
  x_dims = get_dims(x)
  y_dims = get_dims(y)

  #what is the object in y parameter?
  y_obj_name = deparse(substitute(y))

  #set names if matching dims
  if (all(x_dims == y_dims)) {
    #loop over each dimension
    for (dim in 1:length(dimnames(x))) {
      dimnames(y)[[dim]] <- dimnames(x)[[dim]]
    }
  }

  #assign in the outer envir
  assign(y_obj_name, pos = 1, value = y)
}
```

Test:

```
> copy_names2(t, t2)
> t2
  a b c
A 1 4 7
B 2 5 8
C 3 6 9
```

It also works: it does not require using the assignment operator and returns silently. However, it does copy the object in RAM (I think) which is bad when using large objects. It would be better to call `dimnames` on the existing object without copying it. So I try that:

```
copy_names3 = function(x, y, partialmatching = T) {

  #find object dimensions
  x_dims = get_dims(x)
  y_dims = get_dims(y)

  #what is the object in y parameter?
  y_obj_name = deparse(substitute(y))
  get(y_obj_name, pos = -1) #test that it works

  #set names if matching dims
  if (all(x_dims == y_dims)) {
    #loop over each dimension
    for (dim in 1:length(dimnames(x))) {
      dimnames(get(y_obj_name, pos = -1))[[dim]] <- dimnames(x)[[dim]]
    }
  }
}
```

Test:

```
> copy_names3(t, t2)
Error in dimnames(get(y_obj_name, pos = -1))[[dim]] <- dimnames(x)[[dim]] : 
  could not find function "get<-"
```

A very cryptic error! According to the previous question, `get()` cannot be used like this because it only fetches values, not assigns them. The persons writes to use `assign()` instead. However, in the documentation for `assign()` we find:

> assign does not dispatch assignment methods, so it cannot be used to
>   set elements of vectors, names, attributes, etc.

How does one copy dimnames without copying objects with a function?

Comment: Would `attr(t2, "dimnames") <- attr(t, "dimnames")` suit your purposes?

Comment: Good idea. That works when the objects match up perfectly. However, I also want to implement partial matching, where that call does not work (I think).

Comment: I don't understand what partial matching behavior you are trying to implement.

Comment: E.g. matrix 3x3, copy names to a matrix 3x2. The names of the first dimension matches in length, but not the second. The function would copy the first and not return an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to run the `dimnames` call in the parent environment instead of inside the function. It can be done like this:

```
copy_names4 = function(x, y, partialmatching = T) {
  library(stringr)
  #find object dimensions
  x_dims = get_dims(x)
  y_dims = get_dims(y)

  #what is the object in y parameter?
  x_obj_name = deparse(substitute(x))
  y_obj_name = deparse(substitute(y))

  #set names if matching dims
  if (all(x_dims == y_dims)) {
    #loop over each dimension
    for (dim in 1:length(dimnames(x))) {
      str_call = str_c("dimnames(", y_obj_name, ")[[", dim, "]] <- dimnames(" ,x_obj_name, ")[[", dim, "]]")
      eval(parse(text = str_call), parent.frame(1))
    }
  }
}
```

Test it:

```
> t2
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
> copy_names4(t, t2)
> t2
  a b c
A 1 4 7
B 2 5 8
C 3 6 9
```

Success!

But is it faster?

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(copy_names1 = {t2 = copy_names1(t, t2)},
               copy_names2 = copy_names2(t, t2),
               copy_names4 = copy_names4(t, t2))
```

Results:

```
Unit: microseconds
        expr     min       lq      mean   median      uq     max neval
 copy_names1   8.778  10.6795  14.57945  11.9960  15.653  46.812   100
 copy_names2  24.869  27.7950  38.62004  33.7925  39.937 202.168   100
 copy_names4 466.067 478.9405 507.48058 494.4460 514.488 840.559   100
```

Surprisingly, the initial version was much faster, by about 40-50 times. However, the last one should be faster for large objects. Let's try a larger test:

```
#larger test
t = matrix(1:9000000, nrow=3000)
t2 = t
rownames(t) = sample(LETTERS[1:26], size = 3000, replace = T); colnames(t) = sample(letters[1:26], size = 3000, replace = T)

t[1:5, 1:5]
t2[1:5, 1:5]

microbenchmark(copy_names1 = {t2 = copy_names1(t, t2)},
               copy_names2 = copy_names2(t, t2),
               copy_names4 = copy_names4(t, t2))
```

Results:

```
Unit: milliseconds
        expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 copy_names1 4.146032 4.442115 33.09852 12.14201 13.00495 242.2970   100
 copy_names2 4.229708 4.553877 41.39389 12.23739 20.12995 229.4899   100
 copy_names4 5.104497 5.499469 44.42764 13.24267 21.41507 228.7731   100
```

Now they are about equally fast, though the first two are still slightly faster.

Comment: You should avoid `eval(parse())`. I also find your "partial matching" strange in this context.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure how the "partial matching" is supposed to work, but maybe this:

```
t = matrix(1:9, nrow=3)
t2 = t
t2 <- rbind(t2, 11:13)
rownames(t) = LETTERS[1:3]; colnames(t) = letters[1:3]

d <- dim(t) == dim(t2)
dimnames(t2)[d] <- dimnames(t)[d]
t2
#      a  b  c
#[1,]  1  4  7
#[2,]  2  5  8
#[3,]  3  6  9
#[4,] 11 12 13
```

**Edit:**

Here is how you can do this from inside a "setter"  function without `eval(parse(...))`:

```
t = matrix(1:9, nrow=3)
t2 = t
t2 <- rbind(t2, 11:13)
rownames(t) = LETTERS[1:3]; colnames(t) = letters[1:3]

fun <- function(x, template, ...) {
  y <- substitute(x)
  z <- substitute(template)
  d <- dim(x) == dim(template)
  expr <- bquote(dimnames(.(y))[.(d)] <- dimnames(.(z))[.(d)])
  eval(expr, ...)
  invisible(NULL)
}

fun(t2, t, .GlobalEnv)
t2
#      a  b  c
#[1,]  1  4  7
#[2,]  2  5  8
#[3,]  3  6  9
#[4,] 11 12 13
```

Of course, if you need something really fast, you need to implement it in C (as was done with the `dimnames<-` function).

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear, but I was not asking how to implement partial matching. That was not a problem for me to implement. I was asking about how to assign `dimnames` to an object in another environment. I found the answer (see my own answer below), but it turned out to be slower than the copy solution!

Comment: I guess I still don't understand your question. It's very long with lots of (relevant?) code, but not very clear. E.g., your example objects are in the same environment.

Comment: As you can see, I found a solution myself too, which turned out to be slower than the simpler solutions. I have not benchmarked your solution, it looks similar to my `eval` `parse` solution, but may be faster.