# How can I rename columns automatically from name of the data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, rename

I have 15 data frames, which were automatically imported from csv files, each consists of 3 columns, that's why the column names are the same V1, V2 and V3. I would like to distinguish them when I'll get them joined together, so I ' asking for an idea how to rename each columns automatically like e.g. DataFrameName_V1 or something similar.

I have searched a lot for this code,but haven't find any solution yet.

Btw I have this code for the csv import:

```
file_list <- list.files(pattern="*.csv") 
for (i in 1:length(file_list))
 {
   assign(file_list[i], 
   read.csv(paste(file_list[i]), na.strings=c("NA", "NULL", ""), header=FALSE, sep=",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, encoding = "UTF-8"))
 }
```

Comment: I would add as last line inside the `for`: `names(file_list[i]) <- paste0(file_list[i], names(file_list[i]))` taking into account that `file_list[i]` seems to be the name of the data frame.

Comment: thnx, I tried, but it's the same, nothing changed in the tables
and yes: file_list[i] contains the data frames' names

Comment: Sorry, where I wrote `names(file_list[i])`, try with `names(get(file_list[i]))`

Comment: So now the code is:

    for (i in 1:length(file_list))

    {

      assign(file_list[i],

      read.csv(paste(file_list[i]), na.strings=c("NA", "NULL", ""), header=FALSE, sep=",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, encoding = "UTF-8"))

      names(get(file_list[i]) <- paste0(file_list[i], names(get(file_list[i]))))

      }

but the result only the first data frame with V1, ... columns

Comment: And if you try to change `file_list[i]` by `file_list[[i]]` in each place, what do you get?

Comment: Another issue. In the code you copy in your comment, the parentheses are not well placed. At the begining, in `names(get(file_list[i]) <- paste0` you should close the parenthesis of `names(`

Comment: I've changed the parenthesis, and tried the double [ ] , but then..

Error in get(file_list[[i]]) <- `*vtmp*` : 
  could not find function "get<-"

Comment: And have you tried without the double [ ]? I do not understand this error.

Comment: yes, I'd tried both: with simple [ ] brackets, and with double as well, but it's the same error with the get function, and I don't know why. It loads only the first csv file with V1, V2 ...colnames, and don't move on.

Comment: Look at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15303972/r-get-function-error], if it can help.

Comment: I would try `assign(names(get(file_list[i])), paste0(file_list[i], names(get(file_list[i]))))`, but I am not sure it will work.

Comment: I tried, but didn't worked.

But I have another solution:

creating a list from the data frames
vars <- ls() 
nvars <- length(vars) 
dataframes <-list() 
j <- 1 
for(i in 1:nvars) 
{ 
  if(class(get(vars[i]))=="data.frame") 
  { 
    dataframes[[j]] <- get(vars[i]) 
    names(dataframes)[j] <- vars[i] 
    j <- j+1 
  } 
}

Then I would like to modify the column names with a loop (put the data frame name in), which doesn't work:

for(i in 1:length(dataframes))
{
  colnames(dataframes[[i]]) <- paste(dataframes[[i]],colnames(dataframes[[i]]), sep=".")
}

any idea?

Comment: `dataframes[[i]]`is not a string... Furthermore, `names(dataframes)[j] <- vars[i] ` has no much sense